# How can I prove a+1 is another element

Tags: linear-algebra

EXAMPLE. We look first at an example—choosing the smallest possible one. We start with GF2 as the “base field”, and presume that we can add another element, while retaining the property of being a field. Call the new element α; we assume α ̸= 0 and α ̸= 1, and naturally require 0+α = α and 1·α=α.

1. Show that α + α = 0. (Use the fact that 1 + 1 = 0, together with the distributive law.) Thus α is its own additive inverse: −α = α.
2. To satisfy closure, an element α + 1 must exist. Show that if α + 1 ∈ {0, 1, α}, then the resulting structure is not a field. (Each of the three cases yields a contradiction.)
   Thus α + 1 must be a fourth element of the field.
3. The value of α · α (a.k.a. α2) must also exist. If α2 = 0, then α is a zero-divisor—no good.
   Show that α2 = 1 implies that (α + 1) · (α + 1) = 0. (“Multiply it out” using the distributive law.)
   Show that α2 = α and α ̸= 0 imply α = 1, violating our assumption that α ̸= 1. (Hint: multiply both sides by α−1, which exists since α ̸= 0.)
4. Verify that defining α2 = α+1 determines a field. You may want to write out the full addition and multiplication tables. (Four elements and two operations yields 32 entries. Not so many, really.)

Please help .if we have another element a
Do we need to follow the property ofGF(2)
I am struggling with 2now and other questions,I also don’t know

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "follow the property of $GF(2)$"?

IIUC, you are starting with $GF(2)$, then adding an element $\alpha$, so now you have 3 elements, but part (2) shows that these three elements don't form a field, and you need a fourth element $\alpha+1$.  So now you have four elements, but you need to define the addition and multiplication operation on all of these elements.  Some of the values of these operations are already defined because you are extending $GF(2)$, which comes with addition and multiplication already defined.  But you need to determine how to define these operations for the new elements you've added so that the result is a field (with four elements).  Does that help?